# Android RecyclerView onClick with JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-recyclerview, fragment

I want to transfer to another fragment the item that I clicked on my recyclerview. I don't know how to transfer the data that I clicked on my recyclerview to another fragment. Here's my code. The data is from my JSON.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
    holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(listItem.getImgUrl())
            .into(holder.imageViewElliptic);
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked " + listItem.getHead(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want to transfer data  between fragments or how to call another fragment onclick of your relative layout ?

Comment: I want the json data that I click to transfer to another fragment when I click it. I don't know how. I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should store your data either in a `List` or some other accessible data object, and I think you are doing that already since you created your adapter.

Well, you have this line:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

You can get the data from your `List` or something else by using the  position provided by the method, like this:

```
YourJsonData data = yourDataSource.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Since you are using an `onClickListener` you should not call `position` directly, this might cause issues.

For example, in my project I use `Lesson[]` as my data source:

https://github.com/gi097/MyWindesheim/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/giovanniterlingen/windesheim/view/Adapters/ScheduleAdapter.java

Once you get the data you can `Intent` a new `Activity` which creates the fragments for you. Alternatively, if there is already a `Fragment` present, you can update that one by notifying your `Activity` which then updates that particular `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` in `onClick` and send the whole `ArrayList` to the next activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("model", arrayList.get(position));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And receive it in next `Activity` by using this code snippet.

```
Intent i = getIntent();

  ArrayModel arrayModel = (ArrayModel) i.getSerializableExtra("model");
    if (arrayModel != null) {
       String head = arrayModel.getHead();
       Log.d("HEAD", head);
    }
```